# How to move a Netbeans maven project with all dependencies to other machine

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have netbeans maven project which has some dependecies and those dependencies downloaded in local repository `C:\Users\acs\.m2`

If I move this code to another machine, the project downloads maven dependencies(as mentioned in the pom file) on that machine again. 
Is there is a way to move the netbeans project with all dependencies to another machine.

Comment: I think Netbeans uses a local private maven installation and you need to move this instead or specify that NetBeans should use a different path in the options (Java->Maven->Execution)

Answer (score 0):

You can always tar/zip up the contents of ~/.m2 and transfer that to the other machine. That way your local maven repository on the remote machine will be primed with all the dependencies of the project.

Comment: Will that overwrite any settings in an existing ~/.m2 directory on the target machine?

Comment: Yes, if you have a ~/.m2/settings.xml which you don't want to transfer then you can just archive ~/.m2/repository - that directory only contains downloaded dependencies.

Comment: But what in case I have number of maven projects with same local repository ~/.m2. The ~/.m2 size is huge. Is there is a way to copy/paste project specific dependencies(?). Copying all this always feasible?

Comment: To be honest, you'll probably find that the transitive closure of the dependency set of your entire application is quite large anyway. It sounds like you want the best of both worlds - not copying a large-ish archive as well as not downloading a large-ish amount of data.

Comment: @ sisyphus, Thank you so much for your answer. I am just trying to know is there is a way to get best of both the worlds :) . At the moment it does not seems so. Thanks anyway.